# OpenGL: How to fill a polygon gradiently smoothly without spurious star edges

Tags: opengl, polygon, gradient, fill

Suppose the polygon is a hexagon.
To fill it gradiently, assume there are many smaller hexagons inside.
The smaller the hexagon, the pixel on that hexagon has a brighter color.

However, after I finish it, I find that there are spurious star edges between the center and the corners, like in the attached image (ignore the two discs inside).

How should I design an algorithm to make the filling more smoothly?

[image: spurious star edges in gradient filling polygon]

Comment: What you see here are [mach bands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach_bands), which can easily be confirmed by looking at the RGB values in the image. Our brains' edge detection is a bit overshooting with such a pattern.

Comment: Thanks. Then how to eliminate this illusion?